# Guzzle OAuth 1.0 problem with headers, 401 Bad request

Tags: guzzle

I'm trying to replace my own cURL code to the Guzzle client, but for some reason I can't get it to work, this is the cURL request and is perfectly fine:

```
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $this->method,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Authorization: OAuth realm="' . $this->realm . '",oauth_consumer_key="' . $this->consumerkey . '",oauth_token="' . $this->tokenid . '",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="' . $this->timestamp . '",oauth_nonce="' . $this->nonce . '",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="' . $this->signature . '"',
                'Cookie: NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING'
            ),
        ));
```

replacing it with:

```
        $this->headers['Authorization'] = 'OAuth realm="' . $this->realm . '";oauth_consumer_key="' . $this->consumerkey . '";oauth_token="' . $this->tokenid . '";oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256";oauth_timestamp="' . $this->timestamp . '";oauth_nonce="' . $this->nonce . '";oauth_version="1.0";oauth_signature="' . $this->signature . '"';
        $this->headers['Cookie'] = 'NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING';

        $request = new Request($type, $method, ['headers' => $this->headers], $body);
```

The response I get is 401 bad request, meaning that the authorisation is invalid.

Anyone know how to fix? Much appreciated.

Comment: There is a difference between the 'Authorization' header within the curl example and within the Guzzle example.  The curl example is using commas, `,` while the guzzle example is using semi-colons, `;`.  This is all that stands out to me.  `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request` defaults to using protocol v 1.1.  If the application is attempting to POST information, it may be missing a few other headers

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;


$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$headers['Authorization'] = 'OAuth realm="' . $this->realm . '";oauth_consumer_key="' . $this->consumerkey . '";oauth_token="' . $this->tokenid . '";oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256";oauth_timestamp="' . $this->timestamp . '";oauth_nonce="' . $this->nonce . '";oauth_version="1.0";oauth_signature="' . $this->signature . '"';
$headers['Cookie'] = "NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING";
$response = $client->request('YOUR HTTP METHOD HERE', 'YOUR URL', );
$request = new Request('YOUR HTTP METHOD HERE', 'YOUR URL');
$response = $client->send($request, 
              ['headers' => $headers,
               'body'    => $body, //should be array
              ]);
print_r($response);
```